# How to write Command Prompt to a file AND to the screen at the same time

Tags: command, dos, prompt

I am trying to write the output of a powershell command to a file. I have completed this:

powershell psake "Dev08, Deploy-things" >> C:\Deployments\DeploymentLog.txt 2>&1

This is dumping all the screen output to a File... GREAT!!

NOW, I also want it to dump to the console screen too. I have used the argument >CON
but it will dump everything to the screen, but not the file.

powershell psake "Dev08, Deploy-things" >> C:\Deployments\DeploymentLog.txt 2>&1 >CON

Maybe >CON is not the way to go.. Here is a test I am using:

dir > c:\test\directory.txt 2>&1

Anyone got an idea on how to do this?????

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having CMD output the file, let your Powershell command do it with the `Tee-Object` cmdlt.

So for your case, something like:

`powershell ^& "'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'" ^| tee B:\test.log`

Note that the `^` is required before `|` so that way it passes it to Powershell and isn't interpreted literally.

Comment: This is actually great, I will keep it in my notes, but unfortunate for me, the Powershell calls different commands (.exe) that write to the screen as well, so using this will not totally grab everything. if it was a straight PS command, this will work beautifully. Thanks for this info. Anyone else got an idea on how to do this via Command Prompt?

Comment: Hmm, I tried a few external `.exe`s from cmd to Powershell and this worked fine, so are you sure you got the syntax right? I had to use Powershells call operator on the external `.exe` though in order for it not to complain, which I didn't tailor my answer for the first time (updated). If not, perhaps some executables output differently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, I cannot find anything that says you can write to 2 different outputs in Command Prompt. Once you redirect the output to a file, you redirect it. That's it. I cannot find any way to write to the screen as well using commands. SO, the solution that I used was to download "TailXP". Install it on the box and configure it to point to the file i am writing. This will read the file as it's being generated and write it to it's own console screen. It served our purpose and I have it all wrapped up in a .cmd file.